# How would I check if my bots message is <2000 char length

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

```
    @commands.command()
    async def emojify(self, ctx, *, text):
        emojis = []
        for s in text.lower():
            if s.isdecimal():
                num2emo = {'0':'zero', '1':'one', '2':'two',
                        '3':'three', '4':'four', '5':'five', 
                        '6':'six', '7':'seven', '8':'eight',
                        '9':'nine'}
                emojis.append(f':{num2emo.get(s)}:')
            elif s.isalpha():
                emojis.append(f':regional_indicator_{s}:')
            else:
                emojis.append(s)

        await ctx.send(''.join(emojis))
```

This command turns words into discord emojis (like dank memer emojify)

How would I make it check how long the messages character length is before sent so it could print an error or carry on?

Comment: Store the `''.join` return's value and check it's length

Answer (score 5):

Save the string in an variable and use the `len()` function to get the amount of characters

```
@commands.command()
async def emojify(self, ctx, *, text):
    emojis = []
    for s in text.lower():
        if s.isdecimal():
            num2emo = {'0':'zero', '1':'one', '2':'two',
                    '3':'three', '4':'four', '5':'five', 
                    '6':'six', '7':'seven', '8':'eight',
                    '9':'nine'}
            emojis.append(f':{num2emo.get(s)}:')
        elif s.isalpha():
            emojis.append(f':regional_indicator_{s}:')
        else:
            emojis.append(s)

    messageToSend = ''.join(emojis)
    if len(messageToSend) < 2000:
        await ctx.send(messageToSend)
    else:
        # error-handling
```